# Error while Embedding Xpath Code and Inline Server Tags

Tags: asp.net, databinder, server-tags

Grid View template field -

```
<% if ((Convert.ToInt64(XPath("NoOfGuests")) < 0))
      { %>
      <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnAddResByList" 
                       runat="server" 
                       ImageUrl="~/images/btn-addResByList.PNG" />
      <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnCloseResByList" 
                       runat="server" 
                       ImageUrl="~/images/imgdelete.jpg" />
    <%} %>
```

this throws a runtime error "Databinder exception...". I think it is coming because I have not used `#` in inline code. But I dont know how and where. My concern is *I dont want to display there two image buttons when XPath("NoOfGuests") < 0  but I dont want to do this in OnDataBound or OnRowCreated because of performance issue.* Is there any other way??

Comment: You would more likely get help if you put in the rest of the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would it work to evaluate the visibility of each button with the condition? For instance:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnAddResByList" runat="server" 
  ImageUrl="~/images/btn-addResByList.PNG"
  Visible='<%# If((Convert.ToInt64(XPath("NoOfGuests")) < 0), "False", "True") %>' />
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnCloseResByList" runat="server" 
  ImageUrl="~/images/imgdelete.jpg"
  Visible='<%# If((Convert.ToInt64(XPath("NoOfGuests")) < 0), "False", "True") %>' />
```

Also, it looks like you haven't specified your conditions for your If statement, so if you wanted to stick with what you've got, you might try something like:

```
<%# If((Convert.ToInt64(XPath("NoOfGuests")) < 0), "{", "") %>
  <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnAddResByList" 
                   runat="server" 
                   ImageUrl="~/images/btn-addResByList.PNG" />
  <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnCloseResByList" 
                   runat="server" 
                   ImageUrl="~/images/imgdelete.jpg" />
<%# If((Convert.ToInt64(XPath("NoOfGuests")) < 0), "}", "") %>
```

Although to be honest, I don't think that will work.